# Two browsers opening every time I execute the script

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the code. Everytime I execute the script two browsers are opening.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


class TestAplazame(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',
                                               ['enable-automation'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"driver/chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.maximize_window()  # maximize window if headless is not running
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)

    def test_checkout(self):
        self.driver.get("https://cdn.aplazame.com/widgets/demo/")
        self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "pay-with-aplazame"))).click()
        self.wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "aplazame-checkout-iframe")))
        self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "accepts_gdpr"))).click()


aplazame_test = TestAplazame()
# test1.setUp()
# test1.test_checkout()
```

two browsers are opening while executing the script.
I can't find the problem. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I've updated the post. please check.

Comment: Two browsers ot two windows?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Had to used classmethod.